# google map viewport auto adjust

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I found something nice animated route created by @Chad Killingsworth in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm3kL/4/),i just want to ask if it is possible to adjust automatically the viewport of the map so that we can see route where it is headed.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng("54.32216667","10.16530167"),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var path_start = new Array();
  var path_end = new Array();

  path_start.push(new google.maps.LatLng("54.32216667","10.16530167"));
  path_end.push(new google.maps.LatLng("54.32216667","10.16530167"));

  // lots of other points

  path_start.push(new google.maps.LatLng("54.36457667","10.12173333"));
  path_end.push(new google.maps.LatLng("54.36457833","10.121745"));

  var carPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    geodesic : true,
    strokeColor : '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity : 1.0,
    strokeWeight : 2
  });
  var carPath = new google.maps.MVCArray();
  for ( var i = 0; i < path_start.length; i++) {
    if(i === 0) {
      carPath.push(path_start[i]);
      carPolyline.setPath(carPath);
    } else {
      setTimeout((function(latLng) {
        return function() {
          carPath.push(latLng);
        };
      })(path_start[i]), 100 * i);
    }
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust automatically the viewport of the map so that we can see route where it is headed"?  You want the map to remain centered on the most recently added point with a closer zoom level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
map.setCenter(latLng);
```

to the code that is drawing the polyline.

```
  var carPath = new google.maps.MVCArray();
  for ( var i = 0; i < path_start.length; i++) {
    if(i === 0) {
      carPath.push(path_start[i]);
      carPolyline.setPath(carPath);
    } else {
      setTimeout((function(latLng) {
        return function() {
          carPath.push(latLng);
          map.setCenter(latLng);
        };
      })(path_start[i]), 100 * i);
    }
  }
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm3kL/14/)